# Probability density of reactions coordinates (collective variables)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, molecular-dynamics

I'm reading Chapter 8 of *Statistical Mechanics: Theory and Molecular Simulations* by M.E. Tuckerman. I have some difficulties understanding one formula (8.6.4).

> ... If these reaction coordinates are obtained from a transformation of the Cartesian coordinates to generalized coordinates $q_{\alpha} = f_{\alpha} (r_1, \dots , r_N), \ \alpha = 1, \dots , n$, then the probability density that these $n$ coordinates will have values $q_{\alpha} = s_{\alpha}$ in the canonical ensemble is
>   $$P(s_1, \dots, s_n) = \frac{C_N}{Q(N,V,T)} \int d^Np d^N r e^{-\beta H(r,p)} \prod_{\alpha=1}^n \delta(f_{\alpha}(r_1, \dots, r_N) - s_{\alpha})$$...

What I do not understand is the use of *probability density*. I thought that the canonical (phase space) probability density function was simply:

$$ f(x) = \frac{C_N}{Q(N,V,T)} e^{-\beta H(x)}. $$

But in this case the author is taking the integral of the density. What am I missing?

Comment: Quick Hint : Ensemble (described by probability function $P[\{x_i, p_i\}]$) average of any observable $A[\{x_i, p_i\}]$ is $\int_{\text{Phase Space}} ^{} d_{}^{3n}xd_{}^{3n}pA[\{x_i, p_i\}]P[\{x_i, p_i\}]$.

Comment: I know, but why are we taking an average?

Comment: I guess you can think of it as contraction of information : Getting probability distribution function for set of dependent variables from the probability distribution function for independent variables.